# Generate token for service account JSON

Tags: service, oauth-2.0, account, bearer-token

I need to run google storage API which needs a Bearer token.

Can somebody please tell me how to generate bearer token from service account JSON file.

note that I have to use REST API only. I cannot use any java library etc.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?_ga=2.190188523.1922378065.1592250485-1401496335.1588865119

Comment: @coderIam21 Can you be more specific about the environment?